# Adding edge weights in JUNG based on edge length

Tags: jung

I have coded a program which dynamically inserts nodes and edges, overlaying the graph onto an image. My aim is to be able to automatically add the edge weights based on pixel distances from one node to the next (edge length). Is this possible? If so could you guide me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUNG doesn't exactly have a native notion of edge weights (or any other edge- or vertex-related metadata).  What it has instead is a convention for how to tell algorithms that need such metadata how to access it.  For more information, see the "User Data" section here: https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jung/wiki/JUNGManual

Comment: Thank you Joshua, I understand the notion of transformers and such. Basically my question is how could I find the distances between linked nodes and assign them to weight variables within the Link class instances.

Comment: This seems like kind of an odd question, but OK, I'll run with it.  :)  If the idea is that you've already decided where the vertices are going to be (somehow) and now want to measure the distances so as to assign edge weights--as opposed to the usual practice which is to use edge weights to determine edge length--you can do that by iterating over the edges, getting the endpoints, and querying the Layout (via Layout.transform(V)) for the coordinates of each vertex.  (Calculating the distances from the coordinates is left as an exercise for the reader.  :) )